# The project: test which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse

Create a sample code in the eclipse and run the code.

Reproduce steps:

1. Create a sample Java project

[image]

2. Check build path and readd lib

[image]

3. Then get this error

[image]

Comment: The build path is showing errors - fix those.

Comment: I guess, in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ the only item points to a Java version that you have uninstalled. Your Eclipse is pretty outdated and with a current Eclipse with a built-in Java you would have no such a problem. Please check if your software is up to date before asking to not waste also other people's time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The current test results show that the same version of eclipse and JDK can be used normally in windows machines, but cannot be used in windows virtual machine.

Note: Try to update eclipse and JDK to the latest version, but get the same error.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by this and whether this is supposed to be a self-answer.